# Can i core 2 duo processor support 1Gbps broadband speed?

Tags: cpu

Attached images are my computer details. I am currently on a 1Gbps broadband speed plan and my 2 year plan will be due next month. However, since I signed up the plan, I have never been able to achieve even 20% of the speed. Despite upgrading to CAT 6 ethernet cable as well as 1 Gbps ethernet card, my download speed using Okla speed test is often at around 150 Mbps and upload speed of around 300 Mbps.

Your comments please so that I may decide if I should continue the same plan or downgrade to a lower plan at 500Mbps as upgrading to a more powerful computer is still not the time yet. Thank you

[image: My Computer Detail Pg 1]

[image: My Computer Detail Pg 2]

Comment: The connection speed between your NIC and provider's commutator port is not associated in any way with the transfer speed (rather, the second is always lower, but that's not the point). Maybe the channel between prov switch and router is not wide enough, maybe between router and the world, maybe prov's router is weak, maybe all-in-one... Test the up/download speed with any provider's node (the best variant - some its FTP server). In any way the processor cannot be the reason of low speed...

Comment: If you can read/write to your hard drive / SSD at above 1 GBPS speeds, then I think you should be able to (at least attempt to) use the network at similar speeds.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your CPU is very unlikely to be the limiting factor. Especially the CPU in your desktop.

As for the real problem, we cannot tell from the information which you posted. Start by measuring what is slow. Not just 'Internet', but specific details.

E.g. you test might show thing like:

- When connecting to download server 1 (which might be on a 100mbit port) I only get 95Mbs download.
- When connecting to download server 2 I get 300Mbit/second.
- When connecting to both I get 395Mbs (showing that the other side is a weak factor, not your connection).

(This should be less of a problem on speedcheck servers, but not impossible. Still 15% to 30% of max speed between you and the speedtest server is very low).

Next check if there are dropped packets. Not just on your network, but possibly also at the ISP side. This could easily happen if they are oversubscribed.

(Note that in that case you are likely to see higher speeds when everybody else on the same network is sleeping... unless they leave their download open during the night).

Another handy tool is mtr. Basically traceroute and ping in one package. While ping measures latency (not thoughput), a high ping often indicates a problem or a slow location. And TCP/IP downloads also require 10% (?) bandwidth for ACKs.

In short, to diagnose we would need much more information.

But the bottom line is that you now pay for very high speed Internet and cannot effectively use it. So unless you find a weak spot inside your own setup before renewing it is not worth paying for something not used.

Comment: If every 1500-byte packet requires its own 40-byte ACK, that's only about 3% of the original. I tested a 100MB file download over HTTP over IPv6 – 105586274 bytes in, 599408 bytes out, barely 0.6%. (Although the number of _packets_ was nearly the same in both directions, even though I really thought TCP acknowledges packets in bulk...)

Comment: Ok, so much less for mass downloads.  And probably more when mudding, telnetting or similar. But in that case thoughput rarely is the limiting factor.